# Set up a Database with NLS_CALENDAR parameter as 'Thai Buddha'

Tags: database, oracle, calendar, thai

I want to set up a database (*Oraclev 12.1.0.2*) with `NLS_CALENDAR` parameter as ***'Thai Buddha'***, at the same time I need to keep character set as ***AL32UTF8***.

When I do this at setting up `NLS_CALENDAR` parameter does not get changed at DB level. **`SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL`** returns **Current date in A.D** (year is 2016, in Thai it should be 2559)

But if I alter the session and set `NLS_CALENDAR` parameter as ***'Thai Buddha'*** **`SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL`** returns date with year as **`2559`**.

Are there any specific guidelines I should follow to get this done?, or are there any other parameters I should change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone still looking for this, this can be done when setting up the database. Change following NLS_PARAMETERS

```
NLS_CALENDAR  = 'Thai Buddha'; 
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE  = 'THAI'; 
NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD_MM_RR';
```

This will do. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

### Set Charset:

This Should be set at database creation time - **before you enter data**. But if you can't recreate the database, connected as `sysdba`:

```
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
STARTUP RESTRICT;
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET AL32UTF8;
```

Or use [migration instructions provided by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch11charsetmig.htm#CEGDHJFF)

### Set Calendar:

To [change `NLS` Oracle parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm#i1005949) at database level, you must use `ALTER SYSTEM ... SCOPE=BOTH` or `ALTER DATABASE ...`

So for your case:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_CALENDAR="Thai Buddha" SCOPE=BOTH;
```

You must dig in for more in the [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/server.816/a76966/ch2.htm)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

To make your changes at defualt level you need to make registry level changes.

By default value for NLS_LANG, if not set, is AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII. Similar is the case of NLS_CALENDER. Please check below link:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b32010/registry.htm

Comment: Even the changes at registry level doesn't work. Is there any other possible way?